# How can I get the arguments and types of graphql mutations via introspection?

Tags: graphql

With a GraphQL introspection query like the following I get all the field names on the mutation type of a GraphQL schema. In addition I'd like to get the arguments and their types. How can I query these in addition?

```
query {
  __schema {
    mutationType {
      name
      fields {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
query {
  __schema {
    mutationType {
      name
      fields {
        name
        args {
          name
          defaultValue
          type {
            ...TypeRef
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment TypeRef on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Read the [GraphQL Spec](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Introspection). It is really helpful to find out about the types you can introspect.

The recursive `ofType` is necessary to "unwrap" any wrapper types (i.e. List and Non-Null). You can look [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/utilities/getIntrospectionQuery.ts) for an example of a "complete" introspection query. You can also use Graph*i*QL's or GraphQL Playground's autocompletion feature to help you write these sort of queries.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to get the arguments of a specific mutation, you can use an introspection query to get its InputObject type.

Say you have a create user mutation that looks something like this

```
mutation createUser($input: CreateUserInput!) {
  create_user(input: $input) {
    user {
     id
     name
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use an introspection query to get the `CreateUserInput`

```
query createUserInput {   
  __type(name: "CreateUserInput") {
    name
    inputFields {
      name
      description
      defaultValue
    }
  }
}
```

and use the `inputFields` from that query to see the mutations arguments. [gql introspection docs](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Schema-Introspection)